# Detecting changes of an object angular 2

Tags: angular

I would like to know if the object `myObject` has been modified in the view and for that purpose I am using ngOnChanges.

this is my html

```html
  <form class="inputForm">
    <table id="inputFormTable">
      <tr>
        <td><label>login</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="40" [(ngModel)]="myObject.value1" name="value1"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Mot de passe</label></td>
        <td><input type="password" size="40" [(ngModel)]="myObject.value2" name="value2"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

this is my component using ngOnChanges

```js
import {Component, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Input} from '@angular/core';
export class UtilisateurComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() myObject: any= {actif: false};
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    for (let propName in changes) {
      let chng = changes[propName];
      let cur = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
      let prev = JSON.stringify(chng.previousValue);
      console.log(`${propName}: currentValue = ${cur}, previousValue = ${prev}`);
    }
  }
}
```

When myObject properties (value1 and value2) change, I would like to trigger the ngOnChanges. But with what I have done so far, I am unable to do so. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Here a working Plunker :https://plnkr.co/edit/9hlONK54nfiIEcejQouB

Comment: did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43412173/2545680) help?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. But actually, I would like to detect the change globally on the variable myObject, not on each property if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngOnChanges` in used when `@Input` value to a component changes. From what I understand from your code, it is `ngModelChange` that you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use (ngModelChange) on your input:

```
<input type="text" size="40" [(ngModel)]="myObject.value1"  (ngModelChange)="yourCustomMethod($event)" name="value1"/>
```

**ngOnChanges** 
method is called by the framework only when a parent component changed object ref of myObject input.

Answer (score 2):

`ngOnChanges` is only called when the value of `myObject` changes, but it doesn't change in your case. What you want is `ngModelChange`:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myObject.value1" (ngModelChange)="value1Changed()"/>
```

Where `value1Changed` is a method of the component.

Comment: Thanks! But instead of detecting separately that each property has changed, is it not possible to detect that the whole object `myObject` has changed whenever a property changes? Because,if I have several input tags, I will have to put `(ngModelChange)="value1Changed()` in all the tags

Answer (score 1):

`ngModelChanges` is the best option when detecting the change only for the input , but if you want to detect these change across the app :

```
import {Component, OnInit, DoCheck, SimpleChanges, Input} from '@angular/core';
export class UtilisateurComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  @Input() myObject: any= {actif: false};
  ngDoCheck(): void {
    for (let propName in changes) {
      let chng = changes[propName];
      let cur = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
      let prev = JSON.stringify(chng.previousValue);
      console.log(`${propName}: currentValue = ${cur}, previousValue = ${prev}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please made a plunker using the template html I posted above?

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges` hook is only triggered when **a parent component**'s bound property changes and child component's property is updated with this changed value. [Read more here](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f).

To get notification when model's property changes, you would need to use `ngModelChange` event like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myObject.value1" (ngModelChange)="value1Changed()"/>
```